# Using ForeignKey in SQLAlchemy models in Python/Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables that I created using flask-sqlalchemy (an ORM for Flask), part of which i have summarized below:

```
Sites  
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         name        |     site_code    |     site_type    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Aberdeen      |         ABD      |       urban      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Cardiff       |         CRD      |       urban      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|

Data
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      site_code      |        time      |    temperature   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ABD        |       13:00      |         23       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          CRD        |       13:00      |         26       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

My models are as follows:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Sites(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    site_code = db.Column(db.String(10))
    site_type = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, name, site_code, site_type):
        self.name = name
        self.site_code = site_code
        self.site_type = site_type

class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    site_code = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('sites.site_code'))
    time = db.Column(db.String(100))
    site_type = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, site_code, site_type, temperature):
        self.site_code = site_code
        self.site_type = site_type
        self.temperature = temperature
```

I am not sure whether the site_code columns in each of the tables are related. This is since although they have the same values (ABD, CRD etc.) as they correspond to the same data monitoring site, they do not seem related in any other way. Are they related and is specifying a foreign key to site_code appropriate? It is just that otherwise I have redundancy in my Data table where for each hour I am repeating the site_code over and again. The Sites table is a list of sites about 20 rows long whereas Data repeats 20 times for every hour.

As I currently have my models structured, i think the db.ForeignKey('sites.site_code') is not doing anything, since I am passing in the site_code (as can be seen where i define **init** for Data). If I do not pass it in the values are null - when I populate Data I don't think there is any way it can know how to use the site_code values from Sites.

Is there a better way I could structure my models so that I can reference site_code from the Sites table within Data, so that I am not storing redundant site_code values in my Data table? Or is this not really worth worrying about? I need to use site_code when querying Data, so cannot just have a foreign key to Sites.id. instead of the site_code. For example:

```
foo = Data.query.filter_by(site_code='ABD')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , for acheiving what you are looking for you have first to look how to design the model, i'm sure you will need a one to one relationship for that have a look [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one)
and found this :

> One To One is essentially a bidirectional relationship with a scalar
>   attribute on both sides. To achieve this, the uselist flag indicates
>   the placement of a scalar attribute instead of a collection on the
>   “many” side of the relationship. To convert one-to-many into
>   one-to-one:

your code can be here

```
 db = SQLAlchemy()

class Sites(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    site_code = db.Column(db.String(10))
    site_type = db.Column(db.String(100))
    datas = db.relationship("Data", uselist=False, back_populates="sites_codes")

    def __init__(self, name, site_code, site_type):
        self.name = name
        self.site_code = site_code
        self.site_type = site_type

class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    site_code = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sites.site_code'))
    time = db.Column(db.String(100))
    site_type = db.Column(db.String(100))
    site_codes = db.relationship("Sites", back_populates="datas")


    def __init__(self, site_code, site_type, temperature, name):
        self.name = name
        self.site_code = site_code
        self.site_type = site_type
        self.temperature = temperature
```